# Openweathermap API showing No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', what are the alternatives?

Tags: javascript, api

Whenever I try to call the openweathermap API this shows up:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=23.887871999999998&lon=90.25945600000001&appid=9b7d97d1f8bec5e916a02f35a15d7272'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disable

I'm totally new to API and I've also used the CORS anywhere demo but that doesn't work anymore since Jan, 2021. Therefore, what other alternatives I can use to resolve this problem. I just want to test out my weather app. But this CORS policy and all that is totally alien to me.

This is the code:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let apiKey = "<api-key>";
    let lat;
    let long;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            long = position.coords.longitude;
            const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo';
            const api = `${proxy}https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${apiKey}`
            //console.log(api);
            fetch(api)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        });   
    } else {
        alert('This app requires your GPS location turn on');
    }

});
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `no-cors` option `fetch(api, {mode: 'no-cors'})`

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it, I tested it but seems like I'm getting another problem with this message:  {cod: 401, message: "Invalid API key. Please see openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}.

Comment: That suggests that it worked and the request is getting through. You now need to fix the authentication.

Comment: How do I do that? I mean I've been double-checking the API key that I got from openweathermap but still no result.

Comment: That would be a different question!

Comment: when I set the mode option to 'no-cors' I get this error now: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at app.js:16

Answer (score -2):

Chrome does not allows to access APIs which are hosted in different server. This is basically Cross-Origin. This error mostly occurs when you run your application in localhost and try to connect with some hosted API.
There are number of Chrome extensions are available which allows you to connect the hosted API from local.

Comment: What are those extensions? Can you suggest me some?

Comment: Try these - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en                                                  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino

Comment: I think the chrome extension somewhat solves my issue but not totally. Cause now I'm getting this message: {cod: 401, message: "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}. From what I understand, this is causing becoz of the weather API that I'm using.

Comment: Don't use an extension to do this unless you are going to mandate it's use to anyone who is going to use the site. Better to fix properly.

Comment: If you are getting Invalid Key API, it means the key you are passing is not correct. I can see in your code that you are using "<api-key>" as a key. Instead of this you need to use some actual key which will be provided by the API owner, in your case it will OpenWeathermap.org

Comment: For your information, I did use the actual API key provided by OpenWeathermap.org. But in my question, the <api-key> you've mentioned is just for privacy purpose as it's not safe to expose your key in a public forum. My point is, I did use the exact key they provided me but still giving me "Invalid API key" error.

Comment: Open the developer tool->Network tab and see what URL is being passed while calling the API and if it is correct or not. You can also check the API response through some API developer tool like postman to see the parameter you are passing is correct or not.